# magento sql script not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, magento

Trying to build my first magento plugin i still am new to the structure and coding. Now the problem is my database table is not being created. I dont know why my database table is not being created.I tried numerous tutorials and stack over flow, still have not been able to figure out. any help

heres my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
             </customconfig>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <customconfig_setup>
                    <setup>
                         <module>Envato_CustomConfig</module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                      <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                 </customconfig_setup>
                <customconfig_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </customconfig_write>
               <customconfig_read>
                  <connection>
                     <use>core_read</use>
                  </connection>
               </customconfig_read>              
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <customconfig_options>
                                            <title>Email Configuration Section</title>
                                        </customconfig_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Heres my installer script

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `other` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')} (name, description, other) values ('Example 1', 'Example One Description', 'This first example is reall awesome.');
INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')} (name, description, other) values ('Example 2', 'Example Two Description', 'This second example is reall awesome.');
INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')} (name, description, other) values ('Example 3', 'Example Three Description', 'This third example is reall awesome.');
INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('nfrsuper_awesome_example')} (name, description, other) values ('Example 4', 'Example Four Description', 'This fourth example is reall awesome.');

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config.xml is messed up... the *resources* belong under *global* like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
            </customconfig>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customconfig_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Envato_CustomConfig</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_setup>
            <customconfig_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_write>
            <customconfig_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customconfig_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <customconfig_options>
                                        <title>Email Configuration Section</title>
                                    </customconfig_options>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```